# Why does JavaScript parser accept JSON as a function body?

Tags: javascript, json

The other day, I came across some weird code:

```
var OrderSupplement = function() {
      oid: null;
      code: "";
      description: "";
      startdate: "";
      enddate: "";
      gender: null;
      cardowner: null;
      box: null;
      divisor: 0;
      created: null;
      createdBy: "";
};
```

The intention of the code was clear to me: It was the try to define a constructor function, in order to create an *instance* of *OrderSupplement*.

I am baffled by this syntax.

The buddy, who wrote the code, said it worked fine - although it *obviously does not*; at least it does not what it should. He instantiated a new *instance* of *OrderSupplement* and set e.g. *oid* to a *nonnull* value and retrieved it later. Of course retrieving a value before setting would have unveiled the bug.

The effect of the code above is like:

```
var OrderSupplementJson = function() {}
```

My question is:

**Why is the code above *accepted* and does not throw an (syntax) error of any kind?**

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `oid:` defines a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

It's syntactically correct but void of anything useful. It's obviously a bug.

Comment: Oh, I missed labels :D

Answer (score 4):

The answer explaining that the keys are parsed as labels is correct, but I just wanted to correct the premise of the question.

This is not JSON syntax. JSON uses `,` to delimit values, this uses `;`. JSON requires that all string keys be quoted, this does not quote them (it would be invalid within labels).

However, I may know how the author came up with this. Though useless as JavaScript, this syntax may be used to define a function returning an Object literal *in CoffeeScript*!

The following CoffeeScript:

```
OrderSupplement = ->
      oid: null;
      code: "";
      description: "";
      startdate: "";
      enddate: "";
      gender: null;
      cardowner: null;
      box: null;
      divisor: 0;
      created: null;
      createdBy: "";
```

[Compiles to](http://coffeescript.org/#try:OrderSupplement%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20oid%3A%20null%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20code%3A%20%22%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20description%3A%20%22%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20startdate%3A%20%22%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20enddate%3A%20%22%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20gender%3A%20null%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20cardowner%3A%20null%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20box%3A%20null%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20divisor%3A%200%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20created%3A%20null%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20createdBy%3A%20%22%22%3B%0A) the following JavaScript:

```
var OrderSupplement;

OrderSupplement = function() {
  return {
    oid: null,
    code: "",
    description: "",
    startdate: "",
    enddate: "",
    gender: null,
    cardowner: null,
    box: null,
    divisor: 0,
    created: null,
    createdBy: ""
  };
};
```

It may also interest you to know that something quite similar also works in Firefox, through [their non-standard "expression closures" lambda function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Expression_closures).

```
var OrderSupplement = function() ({
      oid: null,
      code: "",
      description: "",
      startdate: "",
      enddate: "",
      gender: null,
      cardowner: null,
      box: null,
      divisor: 0,
      created: null,
      createdBy: ""
});
```

Comment: Oh, nice. Yes, I know, that it isn't 100% JSON - but I didn't know how to describe it adequate. JSON was the first thing, that came to my mind. I asked how the author came up with this. The answer: He looked at code I've written and somehow mixed it up with Object notation - and changed all commas to semicolons to please the parser. He insisted, that I've written code like that - but when he showed me the source he saw the difference.